# Javascript online code evaluator states incorrect output

Tags: javascript, html, htmlunit

#### Problem description

Movie Ticket booking

“BOOKMYSHOW” is an online movie ticket system to book tickets for current and upcoming movie releases across the city in India. The user can select the movie and preferred circle while booking the ticket and the system will generate a ticket to the user.

As an HTML5 developer, you have been provided with the task of developing one module of this website. This module should contain the below pages:

1. Book Ticket page – This will contain details that will be entered by the user to book train tickets
2. Thank you page – Thank you page appears after user successfully booking a ticket

Book Ticket Page:


1. *Label Name:* Name 
   *Element Name:*  name 
   *Description:*  Enter the name
   *Limitation/Constraints:* Is a mandatory field, should be validated. Should not allow any special characters other than space. Do not use javascript, use HTML 5 features.

2. *Label Name:* Movie Name   
   *Element Name:*  moviename  
   *Description:*  An auto-complete feature should be available to the user for the following options. Irada, Rangoon, Logan, Fist Fight. (Name of the auto-complete feature should be “movies”) 
   *Limitation/Constraints:* Do not use combo boxes, rather it should be done using  element
3. *Label Name:* Circle   
   *Element Name:*  circle
   *Description:*  An auto-complete feature should be available to the user for the following options. Silver, Gold, Platinum. (Name of the auto-complete feature should be “circles”). 
   *Limitation/Constraints:* Do not use combo boxes, rather it should be done using  element
4. *Label Name:*  Phone no  
   *Element Name:* phone 
   *Description:*  The text “Enter Mobile # here” should be displayed by default in the text box. When the user starts entering the number, this text should disappear.
   *Limitation/Constraints:* Should validate for numeric digits. Should contain 10 digits. Do not use java script use HTML 5 features
5. *Label Name:*  Show date and time  
   *Element Name:* showdate 
   *Description:*  Date picker to choose the date and time of the show.  
   *Limitation/Constraints:*  Should NOT use javascript to create date picker.
6. *Label Name:*  No of tickets  
   *Element Name:* tickets 
   *Description:* Choose the number of passenger.   
   *Limitation/Constraints:* Minimum number that can be selected should be 1 and max number that can be selected should be 10. Do not use java script use HTML 5 features
7. *Label Name:*  No of children’s   
   *Element Name:* childrens  
   *Description:*  Choose the number of children’s  
   *Limitation/Constraints:* Minimum number that can be selected should be 1 and max number that can be selected should be 5. Do not use java script use HTML 5 features.
8. *Label Name:*  Book My Show  
   *Element Name:* Book My Show 
   *Description:* On clicking this submit button, validations should be performed and the ticket price should be calculated and displayed.   
   *Limitation/Constraints:*
9. *Label Name:* Reset   
   *Element Name:* reset  
   *Description:* Button with Reset as label. On clicking this button, all fields should be reset  
   *Limitation/Constraints:*
10. *Label Name:* Contact Us   
    *Element Name:* The image provided along with the question should be placed in this section. 
    *Description:*  When the user moves their mouse over the image, this image should zoom and be displayed in a larger size (This should be done using CSS3 features)  
    *Limitation/Constraints:*

**Ticket.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>BOOK MY SHOW</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1> Movie Ticket Booking</h1>
    <form  name="myForm" action="thankyou.html" onsubmit="return(myEvaluate());">

        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" required /><br><br>

        <label>Movie Name</label><input name="moviename" type="text" list="movies" required autocomplete="on" > 

        <datalist name="movies" id="movies">
          <option value="Irada">
          <option value="Rangoon">
          <option value="Logan">
          <option value="Fist Fight">
        </datalist><br><br>

        <label>Circle</label>
        <input name="circle" list="circles" required autocomplete="on" />
        <datalist id="circles">
          <option value="Silver">
          <option value="Gold">
          <option value="Platinum">
        </datalist><br><br>

        <label>Phone no</label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Enter Mobile # here" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required/><br><br>

        <label>Show date and time</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="showdate" ><span id="dateMessage" required></span><br><br>

        <label>No of tickets</label><input type="number" name="tickets" id="tickets" min="1" max="10" required><br><br>

        <label>No of children tickets</label><input type="number" name="childrens" id="children" min="1" max="5" required /><br><br>

        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Book My Show</button>
        <button type="reset" value="reset" id="reset">Reset</button>

        <figure><img src="contactus.jpg" alt="Customer Care" id="image" /></figure>
        </form>
        <script src="application.js"></script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

**application.js**

```
function myEvaluate(){
    if(document.myForm.tickets.value < document.myForm.childrens.value){

       window.alert("No of tickets should be greater than the no of children");
       document.myForm.children.focus();
       return false;
    }

    var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    var ipStr = document.myForm.shodate.value;
    var ip = new Date(ipStr).toISOString().split('T')[0];
    if(ip<today){
      window.alert("Show date and time should be either current date or future date");
      document.myForm.showdate.focus();
      return false;
    }

    var totalTix = document.myForm.tickets.value;
    var childTix = document.myForm.childrens.value;
    var adultTix = totalTix - childTix;
    var totalFare = (adultTix*200) + (childTix*100);
    alert("Your approximate ticket amount is "+totalFare+ "INR");

    return (true);
}
```

After evaluating the code I am still unable to pass a certain test and this is the message I get:

> Jun 16, 2017 7:36:20 PM
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   testWeb(htmlpackage.WebTestAssign2): Have provided all the inputs
>   correctly, but the ticket calculation is wrong or The javaScript
>   method is not returning any value false

[Failed test along with message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1eFz.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't meant to help you with your homework, at least not directly. Boil things down to the smallest possible amount of code needed to solve a very specific error.

Comment: You have a spelling error in `var ipStr = document.myForm.shodate.value;` which will raise an error, and then immediately submit the form.

Comment: @trincot Thank you, I did that change but it is still failing the test